# Bound for a Sum containing a multinomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Let $ a=(a_1,...,a_N) \in N^{N_0 -1}$ be a multiindex, with $a_1 + ... + a_N = 2m$ and $ a_1 + a_2 \geq 2$. Further I know that all the entries of $(a_3,...,a_N)$ are at least 2. As a consequence if $a_1 + a_2 = 2$ the index $(a_3,...,a_N)$ contains maximal $m-1$ entries (if all are 2). If we call the number of entries by $|\tilde{a}|$ we got $|\tilde{a}| \leq m+1-(a_1 + a_2) $. Now I have to bound the following sum.

$$ \sum_{\substack{a_1+...+a_N=2m \\ a_1 + a_2 \geq 2 \\ |\tilde{a}| \leq m-1}} N^{-|\tilde{a}|}$$. My idea is as follows. I set $|\tilde{a}|=k$ and write:

$$\sum_{\substack{a_1+...+a_N=2m \\ a_1 + a_2 \geq 2 \\ |\tilde{a}| \leq m-1}} N^{-|\tilde{a}|} = \sum_{\substack{a_1+...+a_N=2m  \\ |\tilde{a}| \leq m+1 - (a_1+a_2) \leq m-1}} N^{-|\tilde{a}|} = \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \sum_{\substack{a_1+...+a_N=2m \\ |\tilde{a}| = k}} N^{-|\tilde{a}|} $$ I can bound the second sum by the following combinatorial consideration. Choosing $k$ numbers out of $N$ and putting them in $k$ positions is bounded by $ \binom{N}{k} k^{2m} \leq N^k k^{2m} $. I thus can write:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \sum_{\substack{a_1+...+a_N=2m \\ |\tilde{a}| = k}} N^{-|\tilde{a}|} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} N^kk^{2m} N^{-k} =  \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} k^{2m} < \infty  $$

Does someone see any mistakes in my considerations or calculations?

Comment: Did you mean all the entries of $(a_3, \ldots, a_N)$ are bigger than $2$ or at least $2$?

Comment: Sorry I meant at least 2. My mistake